# UINavigationBar background image for native resolution iphone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios8, uinavigationbar

My app has a UINavigationBar Background image that needs to alternate widths depending on iPhone screen size in play (4 inch, 4.7 inch, 5.5 inch). Is there a way to create a device specific image such as can be found in the launch screen? Right now I only see options for 1x 2x and 3x. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
– (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
```

Worked for me